# Can I mint 1 NFT with multiple versions on Solana candy machine v2?

Tags: solana, metaplex

I'm minting Solana NFTs. Candy machine v2 was recently released and v1 is deprecated.

I want to create a v2 candy machine and mint some NFTs in Packs, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Candy machine is more used for minting multiple different NFTs and allowing the users to get one at "random".

Packs, such as packs from topshots, would be done by minting normal tokens of each pack type. Those packs could then be swapped(custom program) with multiple NFTs.

Neopets did something like this, and fair launch protocol also distributes tokens that you can trade later for NFTs. You can start there with your implementation.